# K1803 Velleman Pspice problem

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: velleman.png]

I have an assignment to simulate in and output in pspice and compare my results to what i messured in real life using functiongenerator, oscilloscope and generator. The problem is i dont know how to get the sinuscurved display when i simulate, i only get straight lines... I already have my messurements on paper where i calculated different frequencies then compared in and ut to see if it applified. I would really be grateful if you helped me guys :(

Comment: Are you running a transient analysis?

Answer (score 0):

> i only get straight lines

That's because: -

V2 is the wrong way round and there are no power supplies to the op-amps. Neither is there a ground connection along the bottom horizontal connection between V1 and R6.

Comment: wow didnt see that, well i fixed the V2 and there is a ground connection on the bottom line i forgot to place a junktion silly me. But how do i power the op amps?

Comment: Use V2 to apply positive voltage to the pin marked V+

Comment: Oh okey thank you didnt see that i forgot to place wires there. 
it looks like this now:
[![velleman.png](https://s16.postimg.org/5gr3zn4ph/velleman.png)](https://postimg.org/image/z8o6etrip/)
Its stil a straight line though, do i need to change something in the settings?
[![vellemandata.png](https://s12.postimg.org/ep6mxzpl9/vellemandata.png)](https://postimg.org/image/lseidlv0p/)

Comment: Well, it looks like V1 is not producing a signal and it should. Check the settings for V1.

Comment: I almost fixed it, i added a different sinus power source look: [velleman.png](https://postimg.org/image/a5eoqadk9/)
But i dont know what to put in AC?
Simulation:
[![vellemandata.png](https://s11.postimg.org/bymaa8rzn/vellemandata.png)](https://postimg.org/image/s9me6k4hb/)

Comment: I can see less than you so you'll have to keep the faith and keep trying things,

Comment: You have helped me alot thank you, im just wondering if the red line "out" is supposed to be  square like or the same as the green one?. 
I have mesured in reallife 100hz and the result i got was:
in=72mV
out=7.36V
How im i supposed to se that in the simulation?

Comment: I don't use that sim so I can't advise unfortunately.